# Using Hazelcast executorservice with StreamSerializer

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have implemented a StreamSerializer for Hazelcast (using kryo) for a specific Java class of mine. This seems to work fine in most cases, except when I have a Callable that I want to execute on the IExecutorService that has field of such a type. Then I get the exception:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.flir.its.flux.infrastructure.loadbalance.hazelcast.HazelcastLoadBalance
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:298)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.writeObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:254)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:262)
    at com.hazelcast.executor.BaseCallableTaskOperation.writeInternal(BaseCallableTaskOperation.java:94)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.writeData(Operation.java:284)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:129)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.write(DataSerializer.java:36)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:157)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toData(NodeEngineImpl.java:151)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.send(BasicOperationService.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.send(BasicOperationService.java:627)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation.doInvoke(BasicInvocation.java:356)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation.invoke(BasicInvocation.java:190)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.invokeOnTarget(BasicOperationService.java:285)
    at com.hazelcast.executor.ExecutorServiceProxy.submitToMember(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:284)
    at com.hazelcast.executor.ExecutorServiceProxy.submitToMembers(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:302)
    at com.hazelcast.executor.ExecutorServiceProxy.submitToAllMembers(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:310)
    at com.company.app.infrastructure.loadbalance.hazelcast.HazelcastLoadBalancer.performLoadBalancing(HazelcastLoadBalancer.java:101)
    at com.company.app.infrastructure.loadbalance.hazelcast.HazelcastLoadBalancer.initialize(HazelcastLoadBalancer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.company.app.domain.loadbalance.LoadBalance
```

This `LoadBalance` object is indeed not serializable, but why is the StreamSerializer I registered not used ? I don't want to make the object serializable.

This is how the callable looks like:

```
@SpringAware
public class BalanceLoadCallable implements Callable<Void>, Serializable
{
// ------------------------------ FIELDS ------------------------------

    @Autowired
    private transient MessageSourceCommunicationService m_communicationService;

    @Autowired
    private transient ServerTopologyService m_serverTopologyService;

    private LoadBalance m_loadBalance;

// --------------------------- CONSTRUCTORS ---------------------------

    public BalanceLoadCallable( LoadBalance loadBalance )
    {
        m_loadBalance = loadBalance;
    }

// ------------------------ INTERFACE METHODS ------------------------

// --------------------- Interface Callable ---------------------

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception
    {
        m_communicationService.initializeCommunication( m_loadBalance.getSources( m_serverTopologyService.getCurrentServer() ) );
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the serializer:

```
package com.company.app.infrastructure.loadbalance.hazelcast;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;
import com.company.app.domain.loadbalance.LoadBalance;
import com.company.app.domain.messagesource.DetectorMessageSource;
import com.company.app.domain.messagesource.MessageSourceId;
import com.company.app.domain.server.Server;
import com.company.app.infrastructure.serialization.hazelcast.HazelcastSerializerId;
import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataInput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.ObjectDataOutput;
import com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class LoadBalanceKryoSerializer implements StreamSerializer<LoadBalance>
{
// ------------------------------ FIELDS ------------------------------

    private static final ThreadLocal<Kryo> KRYO_THREAD_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<Kryo>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Kryo initialValue()
        {
            Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
            kryo.register( LoadBalance.class );
            kryo.register( Server.class, new Serializer<Server>()
            {
                @Override
                public void write( Kryo kryo, Output output, Server server )
                {
                    kryo.writeObject( output, server.getIpAddress() );
                    kryo.writeObject( output, server.getPort() );
                }

                @Override
                public Server read( Kryo kryo, Input input, Class type )
                {
                    String ipAddress = kryo.readObject( input, String.class );
                    int port = kryo.readObject( input, Integer.class );
                    return new Server( ipAddress, port );
                }
            } );
            kryo.register( DetectorMessageSource.class, new Serializer<DetectorMessageSource>()
            {
                @Override
                public void write( Kryo kryo, Output output, DetectorMessageSource source )
                {
                    kryo.writeObject( output, source.getId().getId() );
                    kryo.writeObject( output, source.getName() );
                }

                @Override
                public DetectorMessageSource read( Kryo kryo, Input input, Class type )
                {
                    return new DetectorMessageSource( new MessageSourceId( kryo.readObject( input, Long.class ) ),
                                                      kryo.readObject( input, String.class ) );
                }
            } );
            return kryo;
        }
    };

// ------------------------ INTERFACE METHODS ------------------------

// --------------------- Interface Serializer ---------------------

    @Override
    public int getTypeId()
    {
        return HazelcastSerializerId.LOAD_BALANCE.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {

    }

// --------------------- Interface StreamSerializer ---------------------

    @Override
    public void write( ObjectDataOutput objectDataOutput, LoadBalance loadBalance ) throws IOException
    {
        Kryo kryo = KRYO_THREAD_LOCAL.get();
        Output output = new Output( (OutputStream)objectDataOutput );
        HazelcastLoadBalance hazelcastLoadBalance = HazelcastLoadBalance.fromLoadBalance( loadBalance );
        kryo.writeObject( output, hazelcastLoadBalance );
        output.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public LoadBalance read( ObjectDataInput objectDataInput ) throws IOException
    {
        InputStream inputStream = (InputStream)objectDataInput;
        Input input = new Input( inputStream );
        HazelcastLoadBalance hazelcastLoadBalance = KRYO_THREAD_LOCAL.get().readObject( input, HazelcastLoadBalance.class );
        return hazelcastLoadBalance.toLoadBalance();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your serializer looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but possibly you have to mark the ServerTopologyService and MessageSourceCommunicationService needs to be marked as transient? And shouldn't the Callable have a standard constructor to deserialize the instance using Java Serialization?

edit:
The problem with your approach is that the Callable is written using Java Serialization but you want to write LoadBalance using a Hazelcast way. This currently isn't working since we loose hands on serialization when you first pass an object written using Java Serialization. I have a pending PR to intercept that and handle it back to Hazelcast but also only if your object is a DataSerializable implementation which also isn't the case in your situation.

The solution for you would be to make your Callable a DataSerializable implementing class and just write LoadBalance instance using DataObjectOutput::writeObject (and read it on the other side).

So it is not a problem of the ExecutorService implementation but of the Serializable wrapper and that Hazelcast doesn't have a chance anymore to apply your StreamSerializer.

Comment: You are right that the `transient` has to be added, but does not solve the problem. The default constructor does not seem to be needed, I have other Callable implements that work without the default constructor. I will update the question with the transient keyword.

Comment: This indeed fixes the issue! Using `DataSerializable` does need a default constructor on the `Callable` as well (unlike `Serialization` it seems).

Comment: Maybe as far as I know Serializable also needs a default constructor :) Probably it change some day. Glad to see your problem is fixed now :)